# Bootstrap Styling issue when browser re sized below 767 pixels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bit of bootstrap code below:

```
<form class="navbar-form ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" name="query" ng-model="query">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="queryresult()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </form>
```

But my problem is when I resize my browser below 767 pixels wide the nice pretty search bar looks like so:

[image]

I want the search icon to the right of the search field how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap 3, the following should work (I'd suggest you paste the below code as is, as I have changed a few class names):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query" ng-model="query">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="queryresult()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Original source from Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

**EDITED:** As far as I know, there is no "bootstrap" way to separate the field and the button keeping them on the same line all the time. To work around that, you could set your input's style to `width:95%` (for example) and class `pull-left`, then give your button a class of `pull-right`, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query" ng-model="query" style="width:95%; float:left">
```

...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="queryresult()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="float:right"></span></button>
```

...though it's not necessarily going to look perfect in every case. You may have to fiddle around with it a little bit until you get the desired result.

Comment: That works but what if I had just wanted the separate search icon (not attached to text) is there no way for that?

Comment: there is no "bootstrap" way to do that, as far as I know, you'll have to set your input's style to `width:95%` (for example) and class `pull-left`, then give your button a class of `pull-right`...